# How to get elements in json vs dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am looking to get value for `loki` in json file `without converting` to dictionary.

code:

```
import json
j = '''{
    "method":"lambda",
    "function":{
        "tesla_menu":{
            "page":{
                "model":"model3",
                "loki" : 45
            }
        }
    }
}'''

p = json.loads(j)
d = json.dumps(p) #looking to convert to json again. 

for key,value in p["function"]["tesla_menu"]["page"].items():
  print(key,value)
model model3
loki 45

p["function"]["tesla_menu"]["page"][1] 
#error
```

output expected **45**

Answer (score 2):

It would work simply:

```
p["function"]["tesla_menu"]["page"]["loki"]
```

Because basically `json.loads == dict`.
You don't have key: `1` in that dictionary ;)

Comment: Thanks... I was missing list [ ] object in actual input..